# Ant can't find method build of Notification.Builder (android)

Tags: android, ant, android-notifications

I followed [this guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) to make a notification
I am using this code on a SDK-17 (minSdk 13) IntentService class.

```
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID=6317;
Notifiaction.Builder builder;
private void startNotification(int backupNumber) {
    builder=new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Backup");
    builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.backup_of)+backupNumber+"app(s)");
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Launchalot.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

I also use builder.build() in other methods, to update the notification

When I try to compile it ant can't find build() method:

```
[javac] /home/edo/Dropbox/android_projects/AppShare/src/it/ptia/appshare/BackupService.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
[javac]                                                          ^
[javac]   symbol:   method build()
[javac]   location: variable builder of type Builder
[javac] /home/edo/Dropbox/android_projects/AppShare/src/it/ptia/appshare/BackupService.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
[javac]                                                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   method build()
[javac]   location: variable builder of type Builder
[javac] /home/edo/Dropbox/android_projects/AppShare/src/it/ptia/appshare/BackupService.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         startForeground(, builder.build());
[javac]                                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   method build()
[javac]   location: variable builder of type Builder
[javac] 3 errors
```

Comment: Can't you do it with NotificationCompat?

Answer (score 0):

[The build() call is API 16 and your min is 13](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#build%28%29)

You can use `getNotification` when API is lower then 16

Comment: also if my target is 17?